# SQL Server 2008 - excluding from number of ranges of numbers

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops

I need help with a SQL script.

I have an `orders` table with a `card_number` column and I have another table called `card_range` which stores `card_number` ranges per client with a column to flag whether it's active or not active.

When I select data from the `orders` table I would like to exclude all `card_number` ranges which are inactive

Eg. `orders` table

```
order_id   card_number
1          101
2          102
3          201
4          301
```

`card_range` table, active 0 = no, 1 = yes

```
start_card_number end_card_number active
101               199             0
201               299             1
301               399             0
```

So the only data I want to return from the orders table is

```
order_id card_number
3        201
```

The script that I'm trying to figure out is the looping thru the `card_range` table...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that card ranges don't overlap:

```
declare @orders as table ( order_id int, card_number int )
insert into @orders ( order_id, card_number ) values
  ( 1, 101 ), ( 2, 102 ), ( 3, 201 ), ( 4, 301 )

declare @card_range as table ( start_card_number int, end_card_number int, active bit )
insert into @card_range ( start_card_number, end_card_number, active ) values
  ( 101, 199, 0 ), ( 201, 299, 1 ), ( 301, 399, 0 )

select order_id, card_number
  from @orders as o inner join
    @card_range as cr on
      cr.start_card_number <= o.card_number and o.card_number <= cr.end_card_number and
      cr.active = 1
```